# City name showing as FALSE on SELLER receipt copy

Tags: php, paypal

Have an eCommerce site built in PHP. After a recent update to order processing in the back end of the site an issue with PayPal receipts occurred.  On the SELLER copy the SHIPPING city name shows as FALSE, instead of the real city name.  This is only on the SELLER copy.

Looks like this is an issue for another developer too, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221527/paypal-city-suddenly-shows-false-in-paypal-when-using-api

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue in PayPal, they are working on it and try to fix it currently. It should be fixed soon.